# not found what is the error actually means. Error: "(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 16 "

Tags: yaml

```
- hosts: local_host
    remote_user: ansible
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
    connection: ssh
    gather_fact: yes
    tasks:
      name: installing MariaDB
      yum:
        name: mariadb-server
        state: latest
      notify: startservice
    handlers:
      name: startservice
      service:
        name: mariadb
        state: restarted
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what I am looking at - this needs editing and better explanation.

Comment: Hi Zydnar, i'm new with StackOverflow: my query is for the error when i use this code to validate on ansible playbook shows the error as mentioned in title

Comment: Ok, just we can't help you at this point - yaml itself is just data - no program - so without code that parses it, your question can't be answered.

Comment: Your yaml code itself is ok - I've checked it in validator. Ok, other validator throws same error for the line where you use `_` underscore - try to change it

Comment: okay, thanks for the format improvement....

Comment: ohh! it still showing the same error

Comment: As I said - before you tell how do you parse this yaml (language / package /server etc.) we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the first two lines:

```
- hosts: local_host
    remote_user: ansible
```

`host` cannot have both a scalar value (`local_host`) and a mapping value (starting at `remote_user:`). Chances are that you want `remote_user` to be on the level of `hosts`, making it a sibling key:

```
- host: local_host
  remote_user: ansible
  # and so on
```

Comment: I wonder why many yaml validators thinks this yaml file is ok like: https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator or https://onlineyamltools.com/validate-yaml but this one throws an error: http://www.yamllint.com/ are there different specifictions...?

Comment: @Zydnar No, different implementations. I can't comment on the first one because I certainly won't solve a captcha just to access a website, as for the second one: When something says „worlds best X“, it usually isn't because else it wouldn't need to advertise it. yamllint is dubious since it doesn't tell you which YAML implementation it uses, but each [PyYAML](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) and [JS-YAML](https://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/) properly report the error. PyYAML is probably relevant for OP since it is what Ansible uses.